# Can 2 tables lock each other if concurrent read/update do not affect same rows? pagelocks off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, deadlock

Can 2 tables cause a deadlock, if the pagelocks are off, and the rows are not related.
E.g.

Query 1 runs for a few seconds

```
Select * from Orders where CustomerID = 1 and DateOrdered between @D1 and @D2
```

Query 2 starts to run, and ends, before Query 1 is finished, but with a different customerID

`Update Orders set Quantity = Quantity + 10 where OrderID = 20 and CustomerID = 2`

(These are just examples to prove a point please)

Now there is a PK_Orders which is a clustered index on the OrderID.
There is also a separate index (ix_Order_Customer) which is a non-clustered index, and contains CustomerID as one of the fields to index. This index has pagelocks enabled.

What I don't understand is how SQL (with traceID 1222) showed me in SQL Server logging that the PK_Orders caused a deadlock when the query which was executed did not even affect the same OrderIDs which were updated.

Extract from Log File Viewer:

```
 keylock hobtid=720229632 dbid=5 objectname=myDB.dbo.Orders
 indexname=PK_Orders id=lock1b0b23c0 mode=X associatedObjectId=720229632
```

and

```
 pagelock fileid=1 pageid=195848 dbid=5 objectname=myDB.dbo.Orders id=lock24442a40
 mode=S associatedObjectId=720229274
```

Can someone help explain how this is possible please, should the Deadlock not only kick in if there were intersecting rows here? I copied the 2 queries and ran them at the same time, yet I cannot recreate the error and in SQL Server Management Studio this error does not occur - the update goes through.

The error in SQL Event Log Viewer specifically says that PK_Orders is the cause here.

Comment: Can you just run your select under snapshot isolation, so that it does not embrace in deadlocks ever?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the query plans and the deadlock graph XML.

Comment: And the `CREATE TABLE` statement including indexes. You can't have two clustered indexes...

Comment: Ok, fixed up the question to indicate that the 2nd Index is a non-clustered index

Comment: what isolation level are these running in?

Comment: Isolation level : I checked the sys.databases table : is_read_dommited_snapshot_on is 0, snapshot_isolcation_state_desc is "OFF" (would it be correct to say it's "read committed"?)

Comment: @PeterPitLock - The actual `CREATE TABLE` statement including indexes would be better as it is less ambiguous and allows us to set up a demo reflecting your actual situation.

Comment: Hi, I think I perhaps am onto something, how about this : in this line " keylock hobtid=720229632 dbid=5 objectname=myDB.dbo.Orders
 indexname=PK_Orders id=lock1b0b23c0 mode=X associatedObjectId=720229632", the associatedObjectID is findable via "     SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), i.name
     FROM sys.partitions AS p
     INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id 
     WHERE p.partition_id = 720229632" . This show another Index on the Orders page which has a pagelock - it contains the PK as well as one of the columns to index. Could this be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually deadlock happens when:

1. Query 1 tries to do an update - but before updating it needs to do a select. So first it applies READ lock (S - shared lock). Let's say it managed to lock a couple of pages.
2. Query 2 tries to do a select and sets a READ lock (S - shared lock) on some of these pages.
3. Query 1 now tries to do an update - so it tries to change READ lock to a WRITE lock (i.e. S (shared) to an X (exclusive) lock). It  manages to do it on certain pages but can't do it on all of them since some of the pages are locked by Query 2.
4. Query 2 in turn tries to obtain more pages - but they now have a X lock (WRITE lock).

In the end both queries are waiting for each other so SQL Server decides to kill one query with DEADLOCK exception.

By the way - issue is not Primary Key Index here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case yes.  The first lock is a keylock so it's basically on the row.  The second lock is a page lock, so it affects all the rows on the page.  So in this case both pages that you are touching are on the same page.